# In angular 14 hide row value based on condition in mat-table

Tags: html, css, angular, material-ui, angular-material

Below is my html code and displyed column to bind html mat-table.
I want to hide row if role is quality and element.tqp value is false.
I tried using ngclass [ngClass]="(element.tqp == false && (role$ | async) === userQuality) ? 'displayNone' : ''" but tr is not getting hidden.

displayedColumns: string[] = ['anomalyId', 'zone', 'hour', 'piece', 'category', 'description','noOfImage',
'scotchPoses','scotchTraiter','tqp','listOfDecision','comments',
'retoucher','valider'];
displayedColumns1: string[] = ['anomalyId', 'zone', 'hour', 'piece', 'category', 'description','noOfImage','createdDate',
'scotchPoses','scotchTraiter','tqp','listOfDecision','visaDecision','comments',
'retoucher','visaRetoucher','valider','visaValidation'];
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

        <ng-container matColumnDef="anomalyId">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >N<span>&#176;</span> </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
             <p>{{element.anomalyId}}</p>
                        </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="zone">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Zone </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" > 
             <p>{{element.zone}} </p> 
            </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="hour">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Pos </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" > 
              <p>{{element.hour}} </p>
            </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="piece">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > Pièce</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
              <p> {{element.piece}} </p> 
            </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="category">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Catégorie </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" >
              <p> {{element.category}} </p>
            </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Description Anomalie </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" >
               <p> {{element.description}}</p>
            </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="noOfImage">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > Image </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" >
                {{element.noOfImage}}
            </td>
        </ng-container>
       
        
        <ng-container matColumnDef="createdDate" >
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Visa Control </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" >
                {{element.createdDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}} {{element.createdBy}}
            </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="scotchPoses">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > Scotchs posés </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" >
                <div *ngFor="let scotch of element.scotchPoses">{{scotch.scotchCount}} </div>   
                <!-- {{element.scotchs_poses}} -->
            </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="scotchTraiter">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Scotchs à traiter</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" >
                <div *ngFor="let scotch of element.scotchTraiter">
                                <span>{{scotch.scotchTraiter}} </span>
                                </div>  
            </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="tqp">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >TQP </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" >
                <mat-checkbox [checked]="element.tqp" disabled></mat-checkbox>
            </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="listOfDecision">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Décision retouche </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" (click)="openAnomalyStatusDialog(element.listOfDecision,element.tqp,element)"
            >
                <div *ngFor="let decision of element.listOfDecision">
                   <span>{{decision.decisionName}} </span> 
                                    </div>  
                <!-- <div><em>En Cours</em></div> -->
            </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="visaDecision">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Visa decision </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" >
                            <div *ngFor="let decision of element.visaDecision">
                                <span>{{decision.visaDecisionBy}}{{decision.visaDecisionDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</span>
                        </div>
            </td>
        </ng-container>
       
        <ng-container matColumnDef="comments">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Commentaires </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" >
                <div *ngFor="let comm of element.comments; let i = index"
                (click)="openAnomalyCommentDialog(comm)">
                            <span matTooltip="{{comm.comment}}">{{ (comm.comment).length > 60 ? (comm.comment | slice:0:59) + '...' : (comm.comment)}}</span>
                            </div>  
            </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="retoucher">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Retoucher </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                <div *ngFor="let retouch of element.retoucher">
                    <mat-checkbox [checked]="retouch.retouch"></mat-checkbox>
                </div>
            </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="visaRetoucher">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Visa Retouch </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                            <div *ngFor="let retouch of element.visaRetoucher">
                                <span>{{retouch.retouchBy}}{{retouch.retouchDate}}</span>
                        </div>
            </td>
        </ng-container>
        
        <ng-container matColumnDef="valider">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >
                Valider</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                <div *ngFor="let validation of element.valider">
                    <mat-checkbox [checked]="validation.validate"></mat-checkbox>
                </div>
            </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="visaValidation">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Visa Validation </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                            <div *ngFor="let validation of element.visaValidation">
                                <span>{{validation.validateBy}}{{validation.validateDate}}</span>
                        </div>
            </td>
        </ng-container>
      
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="show == false ? displayedColumns :displayedColumns1;sticky: true " ></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: show == false ? displayedColumns :displayedColumns1;"></tr>

    </table>
```

Comment: You're going to want to filter the `MatDataSource` itself to remove items that you don't want to display.

Comment: yes. I filtered out the dataSource. Thanks